# Gradle DSL method not found: 'targetJvm()' after upgrading Android Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, dependencies

I recently attempted to update my Android project, and after upgrading the Android Gradle Plugin to version 8.2.0, I encountered the following error:
[image: screen1]

```
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException:
Could not find method targetJvm() for arguments
[build_9slagtuid12ipiv4udzycempo$_run_closure1$_closure8$_closure12@7d583dd1]
on extension 'kotlin' of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinAndroidProjectExtension.
```

The error suggests updating the Android Gradle Plugin and performing a project sync, which I have already tried, but the issue persists.

**Questions:**

- What additional steps can I take to resolve this issue?
- Are there specific configurations or dependencies I should check or update?
- Are there alternative approaches to address this particular problem?

Thank you for your assistance!

**Steps taken so far:**

1. Updated the Android Gradle Plugin to version 8.2.0.
2. Performed a project sync in Android Studio.

Also I got these Logs:
[image: screen2]

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
```